# Returning colors from uploaded images while ignoring compression artifacts + anti-aliasing?

Tags: image, image-processing, colors

Is there a method to return the unique colors from uploaded images while ignoring anti-aliasing + compression artifacts?

Trying to find something that works with image types with palettes (.gif/.png) as well as .jpg's.

The system we're using this for doesn't require it to be 100% accurate, but rather within an error margin of +/- 1 color.

We would be happy to work with a script in PHP, Ruby, Python or C.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at openCV, you can load the image, then generate a hue histogram to look at all the colours present. The Hue values will range from 0 to 360 degrees, you can map each angle to a colour and display them.

This link should throw some light-

[http://silveiraneto.net/2009/12/08/opencv-hue-saturation-and-value](http://silveiraneto.net/2009/12/08/opencv-hue-saturation-and-value/)

Comment: This solution does not solve the problem with compression artifacts. The artifacts that may create new entries in the hue histogram and the algorithm may return an incorrect number of colors.

Comment: Any idea of a solution Alceu Costa?